# Passing multiple @Value into a @Bean in a java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, javabeans

I am trying to write a Spring Batch job that has two steps in it.  They are both the same step but with different file locations.  As such I need to pass multiple strings into the job bean to let the step know where to send the different files.  However, it I try to pass the Resource values, I get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.  The answers I found to this is that I need to add a @Value to the bean to tell it that the beans needs to a parameter to work. 
 But that is for only one value.

Is there a way to pass multiple @Values to a bean using java configuration?  Below is the code I am using.

```
@Value("#{'${batch.outputFile}'}")
Resource outputFilePath;

@Value("#{'${batch.outputFileTrg}'}")
Resource outputFilePathTrg;

@Bean
public Step toServerStep(Resource outputFile) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("toServerStep")
                                .chunk(1)
                                .reader(xmlFileItemReader())
                                .writer((ItemWriter<? super Object>) flatFileItemWriter(outputFile))
                                .build();
}

@Bean
public Job fileToServerJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("fileToServerJob")
            .start(toServerStep(outputFilePath1))
            .next(toServerStep(outputFilePath2))
            .build();
```

}

Comment: From Properties file u cant get Resource. u can only get some urls or data for example Integer etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a delimited String as the property and break it apart into a list for your Value object.

```
@Value("#{'${batch.outputFiles}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> outputFilePaths;
```

With your application.property with the following

```
batch.outputFiles=/tmp/a,/tmp/b,/tmp/c
```

You can then use these path strings to grab the appropriate Resource to be used by your writer.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting in a string, but shouldn't you put in a Rescource? Got one not so nice example that once worked for me [here](https://github.com/teuno/ExamplesSpringBatch/blob/master/src/main/java/Utils/BatchConfiguration.java). Maby it can help you.